# A "too much recursion" error in Firefox only sometimes?

Tags: javascript, firefox, recursion

I have a pretty simple thing I'm doing with javascript and basically only sometimes will javascript give me a "too much recursion" error.

The code in question:

```
if(pageLoad===undefined){
  var pageLoad=function(){}; 
}
var pageLoad_uniqueid_11=pageLoad;
var pageLoad=function(){ 
  pageLoad_uniqueid_11();
  pageLoad_uniqueid_12(); 
};
var pageLoad_uniqueid_12=function(){
 alert('pageLoad');
};

$(document).ready(function(){
   pageLoad();
});
```

(yes I know there are better way of doing this. This is difficult to change though, especially because of ASP.Net partial postbacks which aren't shown).

Anyway, when the too much recursion error happens, it continues to happen until I restart Firefox. when I restart Firefox it all works as normal again. How do I fix this?

I've also made a [jsbin example](http://jsbin.com/aximey/2)

**Update**

Ok I've found out how to reliably reproduce it in our code, but it doesn't work for the jsbin example. If I create a new tab and go to the same page(have two tabs of the same address) and then refresh the first tab **two** times then I get this error consistently. We are not using any kind of session or anything else that I can think of that could cause such a problem to only occur in one tab!

**Update 2**
Not as reliable as I thought, but it definitely only occurs when more than one tab of the same page is open. It'll occur every few reloads of one of the tabs open

I've also updated my code to show an alert when pageLoad(the if statement) is initially undefined and when it is initially defined. Somehow, both alerts are showing up. This code is not duplicated in the rendered page and there is no way that it is being called twice. It is in a top level script element not surrounded by a function or anything! My code ends up looking like

```
if(pageLoad===undefined){ 
  var pageLoad=function(){}; 
  alert('new'); 
} else {  
  alert('old'); 
}
```

Comment: You're linking to a jsbin page while admitting it will likely crash their Firefox? ;)

Comment: Tried the jsbin page and reloaded couple of times and didnt crash. Im using Firefox 5.0

Comment: Well it looks like the Javascript intepreter usually has a limit of 3000 inline calls. And if the diffrent browsers use diffrent intepreters then this is why you might be seeing the error on Firefox alone. Are you able to reproduce that error using the jsbin example?

Comment: You have functions calling themselves, or aliases of themselves.  I'm not certain I understand why you're confused that you're getting recursion errors.

Comment: @Alien it doesn't crash firefox, it'll just give a "too much recursion" error in the javascript error log

Comment: @g.d.d but it's not stepping into recursion

Comment: I don't actually see any recursion.  Are you sure there's not something you left out that may be causing the problem?  Does the jsbin example you posted ever give you the error?  How is pageLoad originally defined (in the case that it is not undefined)

Comment: Ah ok. I thought it was a browser dialog when it ran out of memory.

Comment: @kingjiv, `pageLoad_uniqeid_11=pageLoad` which calls `pageLoad_uniqueid_11()`

Comment: @alienwebguy no, `pageLoad_uniqeid_11=pageLoad` then pageLoad is **redefined** as a new function which calls `pageLoad_uniqueid_11` (the old pageLoad).  Confusing, but not recursion.

Comment: @Earlz Can the issue be reproduced there with the jsbin? (I have two tabs open, and can't reproduce it with the jsbin in FF5.x)

Comment: @pst no I can't. I've reproduced it in Chrome though as well. This is a bug somewhere other than just the code given. I have no idea how top level script code is being called twice.

Comment: did you try to disable the tracker?

Comment: @Earlz i mean google tracker (gs.js). unfortunately you can't, it's added there by default by jsbin. anyway, it might be not a cause of the problem

Comment: @myk google tracker isn't in my actual project, so I assume it doesn't mess with anything

Comment: I've experienced this same behavior, reliably reproducing while Firefox is zoomed in beyond 100%.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code in question -- *by itself* -- should *never* result in an infinite recursion issue -- there is no function-statement and all the function objects are eagerly assigned to the variables. (If `pageload` is first undefined it will be assigned a No-Operation function, see next section.)

I suspect there is additional code/events that is triggering the behavior. One thing that *may* cause it is if the script/code is triggered *twice* during a page lifetime. The 2nd time `pageload` will not be undefined and will keep the original value, which if it is the function that calls the other two functions, will lead to infinite recursion.

I would recommend cleaning up the approach -- and having any issues caused by the complications just disappear ;-) What is the desired intent?

Happy coding.

Comment: What this code works around is that for ASP.Net partial postbacks you only get one "pageLoad" function. (the unique ids and such are generated by code to be unique for each page)

Comment: A partial post-back *does not "reset" the page* -- thus `pageload` will still be defined. The case in the 2nd section is likely occurring. Exactly where/how requires a larger context. (For instance, is the JavaScript code part of the post-back result itself?)

Comment: +1, very good point on this code being called twice.  **Then** there would be recursion.

Comment: @pst, well that makes sense, but this is occurring on a page without update panels, so this is not quite making sense.

Comment: @Earlz No idea then. Them simplest "fix" would be to remove the defined check and always assign the N-OP function.

Answer (score 4):

This is just some additional info for other people trying to look for similar "too much recursion" errors in their code. Looks like firefox (as an example) gets too much recursion at about 6500 stack frames deep in this example: `function moose(n){if(n%100 === 0)console.log(n);moose(n+1)};moose(0)` . Similar examples can see depths of between 5000 and 7000. Not sure what the determining factors are, but it seems the number of parameters in the function drastically decrease the stack frame depth at which you get a "too much recursion" error. For example, this only gets to 3100:

```
function moose(n,m,a,s,d,fg,g,q,w,r,t,y,u,i,d){if(n%100 === 0)console.log(n);moose(n+1)};moose(0)
```

If you want to get around this, you can use setTimeout to schedule iterations to continue from the scheduler (which resets the stack). This obviously only works if you don't need to return something from the call:

```
function recurse(n) {
  if(n%100 === 0)
    setTimeout(function() {
      recurse(n+1)
    },0)
  else
    recurse(n+1)
}
```

Proper tail calls in ECMAScript 6 will solve the problem for some cases where you do need to return something from calls like this. Until then, for cases with deep recursion, the only answers are using either iteration, or the `setTimeout` method I mentioned.

Comment: At least some of determining factors are: method of function invocation (fn() or fn.call() or fn.apply()), function context, amount of arguments and local variables - look at the test page http://jsfiddle.net/9YMDF/12/
Most weirdest cases: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=966173 - some Firefox version for Linux had call stack size ~500, and I've seen one unhappy IE installation with call stack size only 276.

Answer (score 2):

I came across this error. The scenario in my case was different. The culprit code was something like this (which is simple concatenation recessively)

```
while(row)
{
    string_a .= row['name'];
}
```

I found that JavaScript throws error on 180th recursion. Up till 179 loop, the code runs fine.

The behaviors in Safaris is exactly the same, except that the error it shows is "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded." It throws this error on 180 recursion as well.

Although this is not related to function call but it might help somebody who are stuck with it.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, this error can also appear if you state a wrong  parameter for your ajax request, like

```
$.getJSON('get.php',{cmd:"1", elem:$('#elem')},function(data) { // ... }
```

Which then should be

```
elem:$('#elem').val()
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

This will also cause the "too much recursion" issue:

```
class account {
    constructor() {
        this.balance = 0;      // <-- property: balance
    }

    set balance( amount ) {    // <-- set function is the same name as the property.
        this.balance = amount; // <-- AND property: balance (unintended recursion here)
    }
}

var acc = new account();
```

Using unique names is important.

Ok, so why is this happening?

In the set function it isn't actually setting the property to amount, instead it's calling the set function again because in the scope of the set function it is the same syntax for both setting the property AND calling the set function.

Because in that scope `this` is the same as `account` and `(account OR this).balance = amount` can both call the set function OR set the property.

The solution to this is to simply change the name of either the property or the set function in any way (and of course update the rest of the code accordingly).